# C++ how to send protobuf message

Tags: c++, http, protocol-buffers

Can somebody please give me some sample code to do this?  I've been reading and looking at the tutorials but they all seem to cover how to create proto files and generate your message classes and how to populated the message.  I cannot figure out how to actually send the message once I have it.

Here I am populating my message:

```
TestMessage message;
message.set_personname("Lucy");
message.set_image(data, elemSize);

string out;
message.SerializeToString(&out);
```

1. Did that serialize the message or do I still need to write it out to a buffer?  I need to check this code but I believe the object serialized to a string might do what I need for protobufs.
2. Once I have a serialized class to send, what does the code look like to transmit over **`http to a url`**?  I mean are there Google provided methods to do this?  If so, where are they?  If not, then what should I use?

Please note that I am a complete noob at C++.  So please forgive me if it seems as if I didn't do enough research.  It's just that the more I look the more confused I get.  There seems to be so many options.  Just one will do.

Comment: Serialization is turning it from C++ objects into a stream of bytes. An `ostream` represents a destination for those bytes. You need to choose a socket library if you want to send those bytes over the network. If you want to send it over HTTP, you need the socket library plus a HTTP client, which you could write yourself or use someone else's.

Comment: I've not used this one (http://lacewing-project.org) myself due to the poor support for mobile, but it looks pretty good. EDIT: ah but you want HTTP not TCP. Sorry, my bad. Try http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: @DarkFalcon - I have a follow on question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/24521362/1735836