# NSMutableData to NSString - how to know which encoding to use for HTTP response

Tags: c++, objective-c, http, nsstring, protocol-buffers

I'm using Google Protobuf to send a serialized class to an http server.  The command to do this is:
`message.SerializeToString(&out);`  **Notice that we are serializing to a String.**  The server returns the exact same object back to me.

So, in my connection: didReceiveData method, I am getting data.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    if (self.receivingData) {
        [self.dataReceived appendData:data];
    }
}
```

In my connectionDidFinishLoading method I think I need to put the NSMutableData (self.dataReceived) into an NSString.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.receivingData = NO;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.dataReceived);

    NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.dataReceived encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];  // Wrong encoding ????

    NSMutableDictionary *processedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
    [processedData setObject:data forKey:@"ImageData"];

    NSNotificationCenter *processedNote = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [processedNote postNotificationName:@"DataReceived" object:nil userInfo:processedData];
}
```

But I'm not sure what encoding to use.  When I send the data, it looks like this:

```
"\b\x01\x12\x04Lucy\x1a\xd4\xdc;\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\...... (There's more)
```

When I receive the data, it looks like this:

```
<08011204 4c756379 1ad4dc3b ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ..... (There's more)
```

When I init the NSString with data above (encoding NSASCIIStringEncoding), I get this:

```
LucyÔÜ;ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ....... (There's more)
```

Ultimately, I will need to parse the data **from a string** using the Google Protobuf method:  `message.ParseFromString(data);`

How can I know which encoding to use?

Comment: There might be a encoding data on http header. Have u checked already?

Comment: Actually, the data you received appears to be identical to the data you sent.  But I don't think you should be converting the data to string.

Comment: @HotLicks - Yes, we are testing protobuf.  The only thing that should be happening here is I send the object and the server sends it back.  The protobuf method for serializing out is SerializeToString() and the method for parsing from the serialized object is ParseFromString.

Comment: The term "string" in ParseFromString is not meant to refer to a UTF32 string but rather a `char*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [response textEncodingName]);
}
```

Comment: I'll check this tomorrow when I get back into the office.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: But when I use NSUTF8StringEncoding the return is nil, which from my reading means that I am using the wrong encoding.

Comment: When I use this command:  'NSString *data = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[self.dataReceived bytes]];' I still get nil

Comment: Actually, you answered the question.  That is how to tell which encoding to use for HTTP response.  How to get it into an NSString is another question, since nothing I do is working.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code:

```
    const char *bytes = (const char *)[data bytes];
    std::string byteString = std::string(bytes);
```

That worked!!

But @trick14 had a cool answer that shows the encoding type.  That was awesome.

I hope this helps somebody.